# No module named 'matplotlib' error Python 3.10.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I have been trying to work out a boxplot automation program in python using matplotlib and seaborn. Whenever I try to run this program in vscode the following shows:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Code\boxplot project\main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Code\boxplot project\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.08 seconds
```

I have installed `Python 3.10.2 in C:\Python310`
I made a venv in `C:\Users\**me**\Desktop\Code\boxplot project\project_venv`
These are are the modules that show up when i type pip freeze:

```
cycler==0.11.0
fonttools==4.29.1     
kiwisolver==1.3.2     
matplotlib==3.5.1     
numpy==1.22.1
packaging==21.3       
pandas==1.4.0
Pillow==9.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.7      
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
scipy==1.7.3
seaborn==0.11.2
six==1.16.0
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I uninstall Python completely so I can do a clean Install again?

Edit: Im sorry I forgot, my code is this:

```
import matplotlib as plt

x = [24,25,26]
y = [23,24,25]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show
```

Comment: It seems that you are usig a virtualenv right? Did you activated that env?

Comment: yes, with project_venv\scripts\activate.bat in the vscode terminal

Comment: what if you run the script in the terminal where you have activated the environment: `python main.py`

Comment: now i get this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Code\boxplot project\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    plt.plot(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Code\boxplot project\project_venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\__init__.py", line 222, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'`

Comment: I agreed with @rioV8 you shoul try execute this from terminal with the venv activated to see if the error persists.

Comment: Ohter sugestion is.
Delete the folder with the environment. Create a new environment, activate it and the type `py -m pip install -r requirements.txt` with this requirements.txt from the pip freeze.

Comment: I still get the same message

Comment: A different problem might be that you have not selected your venv as interpreter in VSCode, that can cause trouble. Meaning you have the right venv but VSCode does not use it. You can change it by clicking on the bottom stripe where Python 3.9.4 or something is written. After that it should show a dropdown where your venv should be displayed; select it, and try again. Maybe add a screenshot from your VSCode.

Comment: "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'" Well, yes; the `matplotlib` library doesn't provide something called `plot` at the top level. Please check the documentation. You might be thinking of `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`?

Comment: @Code_beginner https://ibb.co/GcyjNG2 this is a screenshot of my code+ interpreter

@KarlKnechtel what do you mean by that? I currently have `import matplotlib as plt` , how should it look like? I just used what people used in their tutorials, but maybe that was from an older version?

Comment: An example with using `matplotlib.pyplot` can be found here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/matplotlib_pyplot.asp)

Comment: In the output tab of vscode it still gives me the same error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Joshua\Desktop\Code\boxplot project\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'` 

When running it in terminal nothing happens

Comment: looks like matplotlib is not compatible with python 3.10 yet. Python 3.9 works with matplotlib as expected.